# Obter arquivo fonte de um módulo Python

Tags: python, módulo-python

Como posso atribuir um método à um módulo em Python ou mesmo acessar o arquivo fonte deste? Tentei através do atributo `__file__`, como mostrado abaixo, mas me retornou o erro dizendo que o módulo não possui tal atributo.

```
>>> import math
>>> Py.__file__ # Meu modulo
'/home/bezerk/Área de Trabalho/Py.py'
>>> math.__file__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__file__'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não deu para entender bem o que você quer com "atribuir um método à um módulo", mas para buscar o arquivo fonte, a maneira que você fez é valida, junto com outras várias, tais como utilizar o módulo `inspect`:

```
>>> import inspect
>>> import os
>>> inspect.getfile(os)
'/usr/lib/python2.7/os.pyc'
```

**Por quê não funciona com o módulo `math`?**

Porque o módulo `math`, junto com alguns outros, não é escrito em Python, mas sim em C, já compilado para um arquivo referente ao sistema operacional. O mesmo acontece com o módulo `datetime`, por exemplo.

Se quiser acessar o código fonte como uma maneira de estudar o que acontece de fato na linguagem, você pode acessar diretamente o repositório do Python, [versão 2.7](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/) ou [versão 3.3](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.3/), por exemplo. Dentro do diretório `Modules` encontrará os arquivos fonte em C.

Se desejas estender as funcionalidades de uma classe presente no módulo, faça uso de programação orientada a objetos, tal como herança. Se desejas apenas adicionar uma função ao `namespace`, acredito que nem faça sentido isso. Se for o caso, explique melhor seu problema que poderemos discutir melhores soluções.

Answer (score 2):

Não consegues imprimir a path do module math, pelo menos que eu saiba, porem consegues com outros como com o os

```
>> import os
>> print(os.__file__)
C:\\Python27\\lib\\os.pyc
```

Answer (score 1):

Podes sim criar uma class e fazer um extend

ex:

```
import nomeModule

class MyOwnClass(nomeModule.MethodModule):
#AsTuasFuncoesAqui
```

Comment: Tente centralizar o conteúdo de sua resposta em apenas um lugar. Postar múltiplas respostas curtas só poluem a comunidade. Logo abaixo de cada resposta possui o botão editar para fazer as alterações necessárias.

Comment: Apenas coloquei em múltiplas respostas por se tratar de duas respostas muito diferentes, mas obrigado pelo aviso

Comment: Busque também descrever melhor a solução. Explicar o que está fazendo, por quê funciona ou por quê não funciona, se deveria funcionar ou não. Quanto mais detalhada a resposta, melhor.